# UE4: Still spawning an object, even though I set it to 'Do not spawn'

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, spawning

I want to add an object reference to an array in unreal blueprints, but I don't want to spawn it in the level. Is this even possible?

I tried setting the collision override to 'Do not spawn'. But it still does...

Here is the code: https://blueprintue.com/render/dvdrvdws

I expected that the actor doesn't spawn, but the actual result is that it spawns.

Comment: Collision Handling Override only determines what to do with a spawned actor in the world if it is set to spawn in a location which intersects another actor.

You can not spawn an actor without adding it to any world. You can add object (`UObject`) references that don't constitute an actor. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong add the weapon class in the array(turn the array type to weapon) , now only spawn what you want and when you want from this array using a different function or as you see fit .